# Displaying MPEG stream using HTML5 video tag inside an Android WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, html5-video

I'm trying to display a video feed coming from a netcam on my Android device using this URL: `http://user:password@camera-ip:port/video.cgi`.

I want to display this content on a webpage, so I'm trying to use HTML5 to do so. I followed several questions here on SO that told me that both MPEG-1 and MPEG-2 were not supported. My supervisor told me that there is a way (probably a hack) to display the stream we want on a `<video>` tag. It is as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <video poster="http://user:password@camera-ip:port/video.cgi" controls autoplay></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works on Chrome, Firefox, and exceptionally well in Safari. Not only do I fail to understand why adding the link in the poster makes for a functional solution (there is no source tag!) but also I am unable to run this inside an Android WebView.

What I have tried:

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // this was for another attempt
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); // this was for another attempt
```

(Activity.java)

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

(Android Manifest)

--

Any help displaying this feed on my Android device would be mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this problem by developing for API level 21 (Lolipop) instead of API level 15 (Ice Cream Sandwich).